# How to make ftp server in react native?

Tags: react-native, networking, server, ftp

There are apps that creates ftp server in your local network so you can send documents and receive from it. I want to make a app like that. But every react native repo about this subject is really old. Is it possible to use Nodejs modules for this purpose? And what i should look for like static server or ftp server what should i search for?

I was thinking to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp but i don't know how to implement this module into react native. Is this the right module? Which module would be the best module for this app?

Comment: That library is pure nodeJS. To use it, you would need to convert it to a react native library. The short answer to your question: build a new library or fork an existing one and update it yourself.

Comment: Thank you i founded a fork for the old version https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-static-server

Comment: What do you mean "do in these situations"? The situation of not finding any maintained library that fits your purpose? One thing to note about StackOverflow: it's designed to help folks who are stuck on some technical issue. It's not useful for questions that ask how to build something. I hope that helps you find what you need.

Comment: :( sorry you are right.